# Accessing object attributes using dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, key, call

I am trying to store the hyperparameters of a model in a dataframe, where the exact parameters to be stored are stored as keys of a dictionary.

The values of the keys are used to grid search for the optimum values in each iteration of a loop.

For example, the hyperparameter dictionary might look something like this:

```
hyperParams = {'C':[.0, 0.1, 1.], 'epsilon':[0., 0.1, 0.2]}
```

And the elements of the dataframe to store the values is generated as such:

```
for h in hyperParams.keys() :
    df[str(h)] = np.nan
```

If the parameters were fixed, the code to store a particular value would look like this:

```
df.loc[row_index, 'C'] = regressor.C
```

However the parameters (attributes of the regressor) are stored as keys.

I've tried this:

```
for h in hyperParams.keys() :
    df.loc[row_index, str(h)] = regressor.h
```

and this:

```
for h in hyperParams.keys() :
    df.loc[row_index, str(h)] = regressor.str(h)
```

however neither are recognised as attributes of the regressor object.

Is there any way to call the attributes of this object from the keys of the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python's built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function. The arguments to the `getattr` function should be the object and the string value of the attribute you want to get from the object. So in your case you could do `getattr(regressor, h)`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Delena.